# LinqPad access to internals of signed assemblies

Tags: linqpad, internalsvisibleto, signed-assembly

Is there a signed version of LinqPad that I could use in order to access internals of signed assemblies?

Comment: Solution below won't work if your assembly signed. Please vote for the bug report at https://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4837733-sign-assemblies-to-support-internalsvisibleto-for

Comment: Thx for the tip, Colonel Panic. I've cast my vote.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. In LINQPad, go to: **Edit**, **Preferences...** and then the **Advanced** tab, and change the following setting:

[image]

And then (as it says in the screenshot) add the following to your project's `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("LINQPadQuery")]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the assembly to which we need access to isn't signed. If, for example, I have an assembly in the GAC, we can't use this.

Answer (score 0):

Extra information for those puzzled how to insert assembly attributes into AssemblyInfo.cs;
Visual Studio (tested 2022) generates MyProject.AssemblyInfo.cs from your `MyProject.csproj` file.

Add this to your MyProject.csproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute">
     <_Parameter1>LINQPadQuery</_Parameter1>
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

After a rebuild, the MyProject.AssemblyInfo.cs, found in the obj directory, now contains below line:

```
...
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("LINQPadQuery")]
...
```

Comment: Starting with .NET 5, you can use `<InternalsVisibleTo Include="LINQPadQuery" />` instead of `AssemblyAttribute `